LT1308 or other IC?
I am trying to power a microcontroller with a single coin cell battery. The MCU consumes around 15 µA or 1.2 mA (depending on if the power LED is kept on) in power save mode. I found the LT1308 to be a potential solution to boost the voltage from 2-3V to the required 5V for the MCU. Does this work? If not, is there another solution for my problem?

You asked something very similar before: Confirming Application of LT1308. Why do you ask again?

You need 5V and 1.2mA max I haven't looked at the datasheet, but whenever Device you use too will need that spec as a minimum spec

What features do you need in the microcontroller? TI have some MSP430 microcontrollers which will operate directly from 2-3V, which might make for a simpler design.

What kind of microcontroller is this? Some(if not most) will operate from anywhere between 1.8V and 5.5V, i.e. PIC16/18f, AVR series MCUs, etc.
